# How to convert a byte array of size 64 to a list of double values in Arduino C++?

Tags: c++, arduino, c++14, arduino-ide

```
void Manager::byteArrayToDoubleArray(byte ch[]) {
  int counter = 0;
  // temp array to break the byte array into size of 8 and read it
  byte temp[64];
  // double result values
  double res[8];
  int index = 0;
  int size = (sizeof(ch) / sizeof(*ch));
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    counter++;
    temp[i] = ch[i];
    if (counter % 8 == 0) {
      res[index] = *reinterpret_cast<double * const>(temp);
      index++;
      counter = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Here `result` would be a list of double values with `count = 8`.

Comment: `int size = (sizeof(ch)/sizeof(*ch));` doesn't do what you think it does. Have a look here: [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying);

Comment: You didn't say which Arduino you have, but [`double`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/double/) might be only 4 bytes, the same as `float`.

Comment: You cannot directly `reinterpret_cast` to `double*` while there is no actual `double` object. It results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @xskxzr You are right that it is UB (the right thing to do is memcpy into a double), but I would be surprised if it didn't work.

Comment: @MartinBonner Some optimization techniques are based on this UB. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/99010/5376789) explains well how this UB benefits an optimizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not completly sure what you are trying to achieve here because of the code `(sizeof(ch) / sizeof(*ch))` which does not make sense for an array of undefined size.

If you have a byte-Array (POD data type; something like a `typedef char byte;`) then this most simple solution would be a reinterpret_cast:

```
double *result = reinterpret_cast<double*>(ch);
```

This allows you to use result[0]..result[7] as long as `ch[]` is valid and contains at least 64 bytes. Be aware that this construct does not generate code. It tells the compiler that result[0] corresponds to ch[0..7] and so on. An access to result[] will result in an access to ch[].

But you have to know the number of elements in `ch[]` to calculate the number of valid double elements in `result`.

If you need a copy (because - for example - the ch[] is a temporary array) you could use

```
std::vector<double> result(reinterpret_cast<double*>(ch), reinterpret_cast<double*>(ch) + itemsInCh * sizeof(*ch) / sizeof(double));
```

So if ch[] is an array with 64 items and a byte is really an 8-bit value, then

```
std::vector<double> result(reinterpret_cast<double*>(ch), reinterpet_cast<double*>(ch) + 8);
```

will provide a `std::vector` containing 8 double values.

There is another possible method using a union:

```
union ByteToDouble
{
  byte b[64];
  double d[8];
} byteToDouble;
```

the 8 double values will occupie the same memory as the 64 byte values. So you can write the byte values to `byteToDouble.b[]` and read the resultingdouble values from `byteToDouble.d[]`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response and my apologies for replying this late. I'm new to C++, I tried using the                                                                            
union ByteToDouble
{
  byte b[64];
  double d[8];
} byteToDouble; but no luck. All I'm doing is initializing the byte array and then and tryin to read the d[i] but its zero for all the items in the double array.

Comment: I tried it again and it works for me. Did you use the same byteToDouble Instance for the test? If you use your Debugger to look at byteToDouble.b and byteToDouble.d both array should start at the same memory address.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is two things.  You have some typos and misunderstanding.  And the C++ standard is somewhat broken in this area.

I'll try to fix both.

First, a helper function called `laundry_pods`.  It takes raw memory and "launders" it into an array of a type of your choice, so long as you pick a pod type:

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
T* laundry_pods( void* ptr ) {
  static_assert( std::is_pod<std::remove_cv_t<T>>{} );
  char optimized_away[sizeof(T)*N];
  std::memcpy( optimized_away, ptr , sizeof(T)*N );
  T* r = ::new( ptr ) T[N];
  assert( r == ptr );
  std::memcpy( r, optimized_away, sizeof(T)*N );
  return r;
}
```

now simply do

```
void Manager::byteArrayToDoubleArray(byte ch[]) {
  double* pdouble = laundry_pods<double, 8>(ch);
}
```

and `pdouble` is a pointer to memory of `ch` interpreted as an array of 8 doubles.  (It is not a copy of it, it interprets those bytes in-place).

While `laundry_pods` appears to copy the bytes around, both g++ and clang optimize it down into a binary noop.  The seeming copying of bytes around is a way to get around aliasing restrictions and object lifetime rules in the C++ standard.

It relies on arrays of pod not having extra bookkeeping overhead (which C++ implementations are free to do; none do that I know of.  That is what the non-static assert double-checks), but it returns a pointer to a real honest to goodness array of double.  If you want to avoid that assumption, you could instead create each `doulbe` as a separate object.  However, then they aren't an array, and pointer arithmetic over non-arrays is fraught as far as the standard is concerned.

The use of the term "launder" has to do with getting around aliasing and object lifetime requirements.  The function *does nothing* at runtime, but in the C++ abstract machine it takes the memory and converts it into binary identical memory that is now a bunch of `double`s.

Comment: When I first saw the words "laundry pods", I was like, Oh no, tide pods are back...

Comment: Note: eating tide_pods is still not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

The trick of doing this kind of "conversion" is to always cast the `double*` to a `char*` (or `unsigned char` or `std::byte`). Never the other way round.

You should be able to do something like this:

```
void byteArrayToDoubleArray(byte* in, std::size_t n, double* out)
{
    for(auto out_bytes = (byte*) out; n--;)
        *out_bytes++ = *in++;
}

// ...

byte ch[64];

// .. fill ch with double data somehow

double res[8];

byteArrayToDoubleArray(ch, 64, res);
```

Assuming that type `byte` is an alias of `char` or `unsigned char` or `std::byte`.

Comment: `char`'s signness might very well be unsigned in some implementation.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi As long as you don't do any math on it or try to convert it the sign doesn't matter. All this solution does it make copies in such a way as to avoid *strict aliasing* problems.

Comment: Thanks so much for the update! I tried the solution but the res here is not initialized                                                                                                                        float res[8];
    byteArrayToDoubleArray(buffer, 32, res);
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      print res[j];
    }                                                                                                         
 void  byteArrayToDoubleArray(byte* in, std::size_t n, float* out) {
   for(auto out_bytes = (byte*) out; n--;)
        *out_bytes++ = *in++;
}

Comment: Am I missing out something? I'm new to C++ so I'm really not sure how  the 'out' is getting initialized in the above function. I will do my homework and update you! Thanks again

Comment: @deepu `out` receives the buffer defined `double res[8];` in the call at the bottom.